# How to use Multiple payload interface for reducer actions in redux typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer named Messages, that will have the following actions.

1. GET_MESSAGES_START -> It Starts to Loads 10 Recent Message using API
2. GET_MESSAGES_SUCCESS -> Completes loading 10 Recent Message using API
3. GET_MESSAGES_FAIL -> API FAILURE
4. RESET_MESSAGE -> Deletes a particular User's Messages/Inbox
5. GET_SOCKET_MESSAGE -> Get's message from socket

GET_MESSAGE_START & RESET_MESSAGE -> Payload will have `{chatUser: "username"}`

GET_MESSAGE_SUCCESS -> Payload will have `{chatUser: "username",nextPage: 2,count: 22,messages:Array<InboxMessages>}`

GET_MESSAGE_FAIL -> Payload will have `{error:[Error]}`

GET_SOCKET_MESSAGE  -> Payload will have `{chatUser: "username", message: <InboxMessages> }`

Interface

```js
// For Reusing
export interface errorInterface{
    error?:null|string|Array<string>|{[key:string]:any}
}

// For Reusing
export interface BaseLoadingInterface {
    loading: boolean
}
// For Reusing
export interface NextPageInterface {
    nextPage: number | null
}

export interface InboxMessages {
    id: number,
    user: userInterface,
    receiver: userInterface,
    message: string,
    timestamp: Date,
    thread: number,
    attachment: any
}

export interface MessageInboxInterface extends BaseLoadingInterface, NextPageInterface{
    user: string,
    messages: Array<InboxMessages>,
    count: number,
}


export interface MessageStateInterface extends errorInterface{
    chatUser: string | null,
    inbox: Array<MessageInboxInterface>
}


export interface MessagePayload {
    chatUser: string,
    nextPage: null | number,
    count: number,
    messages: Array<InboxMessages>
}

export interface MessageStartInterface {
    type: typeof GET_MESSAGES_START | typeof RESET_MESSAGE,
    payload:{
        chatUser: string
    }
}

export interface MessageSuccessInterface{
    type: typeof GET_MESSAGES_SUCCESS,
    payload:MessagePayload
}

export interface MessageFailInterface {
    type: typeof GET_MESSAGES_FAIL,
    payload: errorInterface
}

export interface SocketMessageInterface{
    type: typeof GET_SOCKET_MESSAGE,
    payload: InboxMessages
}

export type MessageAction = MessageStartInterface | MessageSuccessInterface | SocketMessageInterface
```

Reducer

```js
const defaultMessagesState:MessageStateInterface = {
    chatUser:null,
    error:null,
    inbox:[],
};


export const userChatMessageReducer = (state:MessageStateInterface=defaultMessagesState, action:MessageActionInterface) => {
    const{type,payload}=action;
    const chatUserInbox = state.inbox.filter(el => el.user === payload.chatUser);
    const inbox = state.inbox.filter(el => el.user !== payload.chatUser);
    switch (type) {
        case GET_MESSAGES_START:
            // Returns a updated User Inbox
            getMessageStartInbox(state, payload)
            return{
                ...state,
                chatUser:payload.chatUser,
                inbox: inbox
            };

        case GET_MESSAGES_SUCCESS:
            // Returns a updated Inbox with messages
            return {
                ...state,
                inbox: [...inbox,getInboxMessage(state, payload)]
            };

        case GET_SOCKET_MESSAGE:
            // Initiate New Message From Socket and returns new message
            return {
                ...state,
                inbox: [...inbox,newInboxObject(state, payload.message)]
            };
        case RESET_MESSAGE:
            // Delete chat user's message
            return {
                ...state,
                inbox:[...inbox]
            };
        case GET_MESSAGES_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: payload.error
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
};
```

But I am getting errors, saying, chatUser, messages, message not in MessageActionInterface -> Payload type. Those are not a valid type for MessageActionInterface.payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are getting errors within the branches of your switch statement is due to a small technicality.  When you destructure the `action` object outside of the `switch` statement, Typescript assigns a type to both `type` and `payload`.  They now have their own types, so Typescript isn't considering the relationship between them.  Each `case` of the `switch` refines the type definition for `type` but not for `payload`.

The solution is simple: **don't desctructure the `action` object**.  Use `switch (action.type)` and replace refences to `payload` with `action.payload`.

There is one more potential issue which is accessing `payload.chatUser` outside of the `switch` to generate the `inbox`.  It seems like not all action types have a `chatUser` property (should `user` in `InboxMessages` be `chatUser`?).

We can conditionally access `chatUser` using a guard `'chatUser' in action.payload` to make sure that the property exists.  If not, we return `null` and get an empty array for the `inbox`.

```
const chatUser = ( 'chatUser' in action.payload ) ? action.payload.chatUser : null;
const inbox = state.inbox.filter(el => el.user !== chatUser);
```